# Add Different new values to an existing total as previous but to add to column B not just B1

Tags: microsoft-excel

I Have a Value in cell A1 that I keep changing, but need to keep adding it to existing values in B1, B2,B3 etc.

Useing your previous example it managed to get Value in A1 To Add To B2 but not to the rest of column b.

Help would be Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: This will require vba.  Can you show what you have tried to help us know where the problem with your existing approach is failing?

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score -1):

*Following method solves the issue:*

- The **k**ey feature is, shown method avoids implementation of VBA Macro.

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in Cell `F31`: `=$E$31+F31`, fill formula down.

*You get `Circular reference error`, just finish with **O**k.*

- From **F**ile TAB click **O**ption then **F**ormula.
- Check **E**nable Iteration Calculation then set **I**teration to `1`.

[image]

- Finish with **O**k.

*You get this.*

[image]

- Now change vaule in Cell `E31`.

*You get this.*

[image]

*To get new value in target Cell `F31:F35`, keep changing value in Cell `E31`.*

*You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: PLzz write the your concern, that why this has been downvoted??